# jQuery - Get data from table row and post it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table listing student information with a column for a button to delete the student from that table and insert it to another table.

What I want to do for now is to get the data of a row and post it to another php file for me to do a query there. Even one data would be enough if I can't get data from each `<td>`, e.g. student_id, which is `echo`ed in the first `<td>`.

I don't know how else to manipulate the code inside [[...]]

```
$('.btnRestore').click(function(){
    msg = "The student information will be restored to table X. \nProceed?";
    if (confirm (msg ))
    {
        [[var $row = $(this).closest("tr"),       
             $tds = $row.find("td");
        data  = $tds;]]
        $.post('process/another.php',data,function(view){
                $('#notis').html(view).show(0);
            });
    }
    });
```

Comment: you could markup hidden input fields aside the table

Comment: @rnrneverdies I'm displaying a table with multiple rows, so the hidden input fields should be in the form of array?

Comment: as you wish, or you could write the table twice, one as Table and another as a json, for instance. Anyway, is just static data. Does not makes much sense store the data in the html itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an array of the text of all the TDs with:

```
data = $tds.map(function(td) {
    return td.text();
}).get();

$.post('process/another.php', { data: data }, function(view) {
    $("#notis").html(view).show();
});
```

In the PHP file, `$_POST['data']` will be an array containing the TD contents.

Comment: Could you show an example on how to out put the data? I've tried echo, var_dump dan print_r but nothing is coming out.